# Cypress handling big/long fixtures

Tags: typescript, cypress

Context:

I now need to start implementing E2E tests for a webapp that uses a "complicated" api. So for testing one site I need to intercept about 15 REST requests. That API is obviously not well designed, but I can't change it because it is from a third party and my webapp relies on that.

Questions:

1. How should I handle the `cy.intercept()` calls? Because just for one test it quickly becomes hard to read what actually happens, because the interception of the requests takes 50 lines of code.
2. Should I keep the `cy.intercept()` calls in my test file or should I outsource them like this:

fixtures/car-list.ts

```
export function mockCarList() {
 cy.intercept()
 cy.intercept()
 ...
}
```

integration/car-list.spec.ts

```
import { mockCarList } from '../fixtures/car-list'

describe('Test car', () => {
  it('Should test car list', () => {
    mockCarList();
    
    do test stuff
  });
});
```

Comment: If your `mockCarList()` will only be used in one spec, then just move it inside the spec file, but outside of your test blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is valid, but don't put the function in `fixtures` because it's not really a fixture (i.e. data).

Put it in `/cypress/support/commands.js` and make it a custom command so that you don't need to import it into the test.

```js
// command.js

Cypress.Commands.add('mockCarList', function() {
  cy.intercept()
  cy.intercept()
  ...
}
```

**Test**

```js
describe('Test car', () => {
  it('Should test car list', () => {
    cy.mockCarList();
    
    do test stuff
  });
});
```

Comment: I was also thinking about moving the intercepts in cypress commands. But when you put them all in this file `/cypress/support/commands.js` then it becomes hard to distinguish "intercept" commands from the default commands. So the commands file would get messy

Comment: You can use any files you want in the `/cypress/support` folder, for example `intercept-commands.js`. Just make sure to import them into `/cypress/support/index.js` in the same way `commands.js` is currently imported.